# Django script that runs when the server starts

Tags: django, model

Hi is it possible to create a script that runs when the server starts? I want a script that creates a few objects of a model so that a user has at least a few options to choose from before deciding to create a new one.

I would like the script to just create a few MemberRole objects so that when creating a member the role field has a few by default.

Would running a script be the ideal way to do this?

```
class Member(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    role = models.ForeignKey(MemberRole)

class MemberRole(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at this documentation page: [Providing initial data for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

You can create a JSON, XML or YAML fixture to load your data with `manage.py loaddata` admin command.

By the way automatic loading of data fixtures on database creation will be deprecated in favor of [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

Comment: FYI, in case of django < 1.7, you can use `south` and use [data migrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations).